# How can I optimise my multi-class build for damage and survivability? (Rogue-Druid-Warlock)

Tags: dnd-5e, optimization, multi-classing

I need some support with optimising this multi-class build.

I'm playing in a D&D 5e party where we receive high incoming damage.Our GM is allowing us to multi-class and use feats and spells from the core books as well as Unearthed Arcana (UA), e.g. Feat/Spells from 2020 UA relases. The storyline in our campaign is likely to come to an end when we reach L12; so, I have another 4 levels probably.

My PC is a Satyr and my stats are:
Str (8), Dex (16), Con (16), Int (9), Wis (16), Cha (16)

The build I have chosen so far is:

- L3 Rogue (The Revived) UA
- L2 Warlock (Hexblade) XGtE
- L3 Druid (Circle of Spores) UA

I have chosen my classes and sub-classes but:

Where do I go from here - what is the best order to level **my next 4 levels**?

#### Criteria are: single-target damage / survivability / action economy

1. I want my main role to be damage support on single targets
2. I also want to be able to survive/escape with ease

Note: I have not chosen my *two* Eldritch Invocations yet.

Comment: I’m voting to close as opinion based. Your criteria need to be improved before we can help you. You have two criteria it seems: single target damage and survivability. The first is objective, the second is opinion, and part of answering your question is striking a balance between the two, another matter of opinion.

Comment: I'm not sure I agree; I've seen other questions that ask about balancing between two different roles and those are just fine. I do not believe this is opinion based.

Comment: Are you limiting yourself to these classes or is further multiclassing acceptable? Also, I am not sure how to compare your two criteria (eg. would dealing 1d6 fewer damage but having +10ft speed be worth it?).

Comment: @ThomasMarkov Hi, I did try delimit the criteria.  The main role is damage output on single targets, but the campaign we are in has very high damage to players the mobs do more damage than in the MM normally and crit damage does additional damage.

Comment: @Szega Thank you - I am limited now to these 3 sub-classes. However, I have not chosen my two Eldricht Invocations yet, so I will update my question. Thanks.

Comment: @NathanS - Thank you - I added the optimization tag as it seems relevant.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## I'd take two levels in Druid and two levels in Rogue

Two levels in Rogue gives you an ASI, Uncanny Dodge, and an increase in sneak damage. Two level in Druid gives you another ASI, a cantrip and access to 3rd level spells plus more spell slots.

So, Uncanny Dodge lets you halve the damage of an incoming attack using your reaction, which will help with survivability. Also the extra sneak damage is nice for increasing your damage output against single targets.

Your 3rd level druid spells gives you access to a variety of options, such as *conjure animals* (giving your foes 8 more targets really helps with survivability), and *gaseous form* from your Circle of Spores subclass, which is a good way to escape if things go badly.

Your ASIs could either bump DEX (increases attack, damage and AC), or take the Tough feat for a big chunk of extra HP (better taken later though, since at level 8 that's 16 more HP but at level 11 that's 22 more HP; doesn't matter that much though, since it'll end up giving you 22 more HP by 11th level either way).

Defensive Duelist also gives you a way to increase your AC by +4 (from 9th level onwards), but it uses your reaction so it's competing with Uncanny Dodge, so maybe not the best choice.

Finally, your 2 Eldritch Invocations; unless you have magical armour, then using *mage armor* via Armor of Shadows will be your best option for AC (if you increase DEX with an ASI, it will also out-compete medium armour like Half-Plate, and doesn't affect stealth or make your armour a target for *heat metal*).

There's also Fiendish Vigor, which lets you have 5 temp HP via *false life*, but it will take up your action, so maybe something you want to pre-cast rather than rely on in combat. That said, this won't stack with your temp HP from Symbiotic Entity from your Circle of Spores, so this might be a bit wasted on you.

A better choice might be Repelling Blast, which you can use to push enemies away with *eldritch blast* if you're trying to create distance between you and them but still deal damage.

## Alternatively, replace the levels in Rogue for two level in Warlock

As an alternative, you could swap the two levels in Rogue from my above suggestion for Warlock, which means you lose Uncanny Dodge and the extra sneak die, but you gain a Pact Boon (you get an ASI either way).

Although I dismissed Pact Boons above, the Pact of the Chain combined with the Gift of the Ever-Living Ones invocation means that you can recieve max healing. This, combined with *cure wounds*/*healing word* from Druid means that you can just give yourself a flat 11 HP (from a 1st level *cure wounds*, for example), which is good for survivability.

You lose out on an extra sneak attack die, though, so this comes at the cost of increased damage output. Also, you lose Uncanny Dodge, as I said above, but arguably this now makes Defensive Duelist look more appealing.

Comment: Thank you - really appreciate the extensive answer. I will be able to playtest this very soon. Opting for +2 levels in Rogue and +2 in Druid for the ASI, Uncanny Dodge and acces to *conjure animals*. I can see that upping my damage considerably while balancing out with survivability. :) Ta'